# PHP - How can I get the name of a POST technique from one page to another?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm posting a select option from one page to another, on my actual server code (PHP), I'm wanting to firstly, get the POST name, for example, $_POST['selection_value'] and secondly, check if it's equal to a value from the selection, like : if($_POST['selection_value'] == 'time') {} . (time is the value of a selection option). How would I go about doing this ?

My code for the POST grab :

***The markup***

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 4%;">
<div class="form-group m-r-12">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label";">Add User</label>
</div>

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" required />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required />
<input type="text" name="cpukey" id="cpukey" placeholder="CPUKey" class="form-control" required />
<button onclick="addUser()" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Add User</button>

<select class="form-control" id="selection_value" name="selection_value">
    <option value="account_credits">Account Credits</option>
    <option value="free_gifted_credits">Free Gifted Credits</option>
    <option value="time">Member Server Days</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="add_to_all_value" id="add_to_all_value" placeholder="Value to add to current" class="form-control" required />
<button id="button1" onclick="add_to_all()" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Add To All Users</button>
```

*The AJAX*

```
            function add_to_all() {
            myOutput = document.getElementById('add_user_result');
            var member_selection  = $('#selection_value :selected').text()
            var member_value      =  $('#add_to_all_value').val();

            if(member_selection != "" & member_value != "") {
                $.ajax ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'includes/ajax_data_add_to_all.php',
                    data: { selection: member_selection, value: member_value },
                    success:function(response) {
                        $("#add_user_result").show();
                        $('#add_user_result').fadeOut(3000).html(response);
                        header('Location: admin_members.php'); 
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $("#add_user_result").show();
                        $('#add_user_result').fadeOut(3000).html(response);
                        header('Location: admin_members.php');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#add_user_result").show();
                $('#add_user_result').fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(3000);
                myOutput.innerHTML = "<font style='color: red;'>You must fill in all the blanks.</font>";
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Now my code for the add time (server code) :

```
    function grab_all_time() {
global $con;
    $usersTime   = "SELECT time FROM users";
    $result             = $con->query($usersTime) or die("Error");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            return $row['time'];
        }
}

$AllusersTime = grab_all_time();

if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST)) {
    $selection          = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['selection']);
    $value              = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['value']);

    $membersDate = new DateTime($AllusersTime);
    $membersDate->add(new DateInterval('P'.$value.'D'));
    $finishedDT = $membersDate->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

    if($selection == 'Member Server Days') {
        $insert_query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET '".$selection."' + '".$value."'");
        if($insert_query) {
            echo '<font style="color: green;">Successfully Added to all users</font>';
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=admin_members.php">';
        }
        else {
            echo '<font style="color: red;">Failed to add to all users</font>';
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=admin_members.php">';
        }
    } else {
        $insert_query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET time = '".$finishedDT."'");
        if($insert_query) {
            echo '<font style="color: green;">Successfully Added to all users</font>';
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=admin_members.php">';
        }
        else {
            echo '<font style="color: red;">Failed to add to all users</font>';
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=admin_members.php">';
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried with var member_selection  = $('#selection_value :selected').val() not text() ?

Comment: yes, but it echos Failed to add to all users.

Comment: the function `grab_all_time` will return only one row as the return statement is in the loop

Comment: what is the $selection value you got in the php ?

Comment: the selection value is the post from the ajax from the other page : data: { selection: member_selection, value: member_value }, the selection value Im trying to get the name of is time

Comment: @RamRaider Okay, How would I got about doing it correctly then ?

Comment: Hello Ben Za (nice avatar!), can you try to explain what you try to do with `grab_all_time`? It's unclear what you try to do with it. As the exception says, you can only pass a string to `DateTime` and not an array (what you get from grabbing all times). Possibly you want to filter the rows by the actual user (and only update his/her record).

Comment: @CharlotteDunois - grab_all_time needs to grab each specific users expirey time in the format 00-00-00 00:00:00 then I add the value of what's typed in to my input to the users date. I don't want it to make every users time the same, I just want to add for example, 1 day to each specific date.

Comment: Then you need to loop over the array and update each specific time with a where clausel. You should do that directly in the loop of your function.

Answer (score 0):

To return all records for the query in your function `grab_all_time` you could use an array, add each result to it and return that array:

```
function grab_all_time() {
    global $con;
    $usersTime = "SELECT time FROM users";
    $result = $con->query($usersTime) or die("Error");

    $results = array();
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $results[]=$row['time'];
    }
    return $results;
}
```

That obviously returns an array so you can't simply assign the return value as a `DateTime` object which you later go on to do. If it is just the one result from the query you need to process then why fetch all rows?

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['selection'], $_POST['value'] ) ){

    $selection          = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_POST['selection'] );
    $value              = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_POST['value'] );   

    $AllusersTime = grab_all_time();
    foreach( $AllusersTime as $i => $time ){
        $membersDate = new DateTime( $time );
        $membersDate->add( new DateInterval('P'.$value.'D') );
        $finishedDT = $membersDate->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

        /* .... the rest of you code .... */
        /* dont add the `meta refresh` */
    }

}
```

Still a trifle confused with what you actually wish to do - hopefully I have understood correctly in that you wish to update each user's record according to values and options selected. To update each record individually using pre-existing content in each of their records using a where clause for the update statement would seem logical.

I think my confusion stems from the sql that retrieves data from the users table in your function. The way it was originally structured meant that despite selecting all records you returned only the first one in the recordset and used that as the basis for the remaining code. If, and I say IF, you intended to return ALL records and process them individually then returning an array from your function seems the best option.

You will note I modified ( again ) your function to also get the `user_id` associated with each record - substitute that for the correct column name.

```
function grab_all_time() {
    global $con;
    /* NOTE: assumed a column `user_id` !! */
    $usersTime = "SELECT `user_id`,`time` FROM `users`;";
    $result = $con->query($usersTime) or die("Error");

    $results = array();
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        /* NOTE: assumed column `user_id` !! */
        $results[ $row['user_id'] ]=$row['time'];
    }
    return $results;
}






if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['selection'], $_POST['value'] ) ){

    $selection  = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_POST['selection'] );
    $value      = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, $_POST['value'] );   

    $AllusersTime = grab_all_time();
    $results = array();


    foreach( $AllusersTime as $user_id => $time ){

        $membersDate = new DateTime( $time );
        $membersDate->add( new DateInterval('P'.$value.'D') );
        $finishedDT = $membersDate->format('Y-m-d');

        /* .... the rest of you code .... */
        if( $selection == 'Member Server Days' ) {
            $sql='update `users` set `'.$selection.'`=`'.$selection.'` + '.$value.' where `user_id`="'.$user_id.'";';
        } else {
            $sql='update `users` set `time`="'.$finishedDT.'" where `user_id`="'.$user_id.'";';
        }

        $results[ $user_id ]=mysqli_query( $con, $sql ) ? 'Success' : 'Fail';
    }





    echo '<pre>',print_r( $results, true ),'</pre>';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="3; URL=admin_members.php">';
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do with your code. If it is to update ALL users with the same data or update individual records??

Comment: thank you so much. But for my other selection options, when i type in 1.00 for the free_gifted_credits, it says bad dateTime format. How can I make it only require a dateTime format for time value post?

Comment: `intval()` springs to mind if you want to use an integer. Are you saying that there is a column called `Member Server Days` in the db table? This is how your code and consequently this code would be interpreted. What I see in the Pastebin is totally different to that shown here